# I'm using Clipboard.GetDataObject(); but sometimes it does not function like I need

Tags: c#, clipboard

This is the function I'm using

```
    public String ClipboardGet()
    {
        IDataObject dataObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

        if (!dataObj.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            return "";

        return dataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
    }
```

but sometimes it returns a empty string even when the data is text, how to handel this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`Clipboard.GetText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kz40084e.aspx) or [`IDataObject.GetDataPresent(string, bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1yc0tt01.aspx)?